# How to open a kotlin fragment from java Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment

I have an activity `MainActivity` in java  and a fragment `FirstFragment` in Kotlin,
write code in `MainActivity` to open `FirstFragment`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.my_container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call kotlin and java from each other, you just import the class and call it. Does not matter if it is kotlin or not.